# Referring to groups and unnamed individuals from groups in a screenplay

Tags: characters, formatting, screenwriting, naming

The following extract is from a screenplay I'm writing. I could really use some advice on how to format it, particularly around referring to groups of people and an unnamed person from a group.

> Bob watches as a group of YOUNG WOMEN dance.
>   He turns his attention to a group of MIDDLE-AGED MEN talking at a table.
>   They continually glance over at the Young Women.
>   The Young Women head to the exit.
>   Bob watches the Men.
>   A MAN from the group gets up and walks to the bar.

Is it right to refer to e.g. the group of young women as 'Young Women' with capitalised first letters? The same question for 'Men'.
I am also not sure how to refer to the 'MAN' from the group, does it look OK as is? He doesn't have a name or dialog and doesn't have any further role in the screenplay.

Comment: To the downvoter and/or close-voter: this question is *not* asking for a critique. It's asking how to format a screenplay, and that's perfectly on-topic here. Including a snippet of one's screenplay in order to illustrate the problem is both allowed and encouraged.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm not asking for critique. I even simplified the lines to keep focus on the question I have so this is not something I would want critiqued anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are non-speaking characters in a screenplay introduced in all caps?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19221/are-non-speaking-characters-in-a-screenplay-introduced-in-all-caps)

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 1):

When I write musicals, I reffer to my un-named people with a general word, such as Students or Monkeys, with capitalization. When a named characters says a word such as "Students" or "Monkeys" I don't capitalize it. Capitilization matters.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in theatre in high school this was the way it was done.

The people, if nameless or in a group like above, were mentioned in big letters. I've seen the roles, when they mentioned to be doing an action, to be in big capital letters, for all the letters, not just the first.

Oh, and characters can be referred to as young women, men, or whatever else in a script.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** You should change ALL of the character's names to all-caps. Characters, whether they do an action or have an action be done to them is in all-caps. When one character talks to another, the character does not have to be in all-caps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in screenwriting the format is different - characters are only written in all-caps when they are first introduced.

Comment: @petehallw Ah, ok. Just bringing to the table what I know.